# Twistor equation and Killing equation

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, spinors, twistor

Yesterday was the birthday of Roger Penrose. And reading again about twistors I realized that twistor equation is strikingly similar to a Killing equation. My question is, are they "equivalent"? If not, when?

Twistor equation: $$\nabla^{(A\; }_{\; A'}\phi^{C)}=0$$

Killing equation reads. $$\nabla_{(\mu}\xi_{\nu)}=0$$

Can the similarity work also for multispinor twistor equation and Killing tensors? That is,...Let us write a more general twistor equation

$$\nabla^{(A_1}_{\; A'}\phi^{A_2\cdots A_r)}=0$$

$$\nabla_{(\alpha} K_{\beta_1\beta_2\cdots \beta_m)}=0$$

They are strikingly similar, and after a suitable redefinition of indices (and of course taking into account the difference between spinor and space-time indices) are essentially the same. Are there relations between general tensor Killing fields/forms and twistor-like variables/equations?

Bonus: Indeed, the Weyl equation is also very similare to the twistor equation, but only with antisymmetric spin connection instead the symmetric part. Any relation too of weyl equations to twistors?

Comment: Yes they are equivalent. There is a whole dedicated discussion on this topic on section 6.5 - 6.7 from "Spinors and Spacetime" Volume - 2